# Replication broke table compression and partition though I can still see the ndf files having data sql server

Tags: sql-server, replication, partitioning

I recently did a backup of a table,compressed it and partition it.Then I did replication to it using the filter option to get latest data.Now I can only see the latest records and not the old records but the ndf files are there.

Is there a way to recover these records?I mean tie back the partition to this table so that I can see the data?

Comment: What backups do you have for the database (using the BACKUP DATABASE command) and what is the recovery model for the database? You are likely in for a restore, possibly into another database and the copy the desired data to your database.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Thank you for your response. After digging into more research, Seems that I will have to do a restore to save time.

Comment: Is this the same as: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291499/partitioned-table-replication-reverted-to-primary-filegroup-can-i-re-link-to ?

Comment: @Cris You and Quade need to coordinate your activity here.